# Sql Server 2012 Search value character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, search

I'm trying to find a value (1 character) inside a string which is separated by (:) colon, I'm trying to use the CHARINDEX function but it's not working at 100% since it returns strings that contain values I do not want him to return.

Example:

Value = 1: 2: 1
acceptable

Value = 1: 23: 1
not acceptable

Value = 2: 1: 1
acceptable

Value = 1: 1: 2
acceptable

Value = 3: 23: 1
not acceptable

Code:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('2', ltrim(rtrim(replace(AA,' ',''))) ) ,
    FROM table
where CHARINDEX('2', ltrim(rtrim(replace(AA,' ',''))) ) > 0
```

How could I do to show me only the "acceptable"

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks for the support !

Comment: You r rule isn't clear. Are you looking for records that have a single digit of 2 in at least one of the segments?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of: append ':' in both start and end of the string and then do charindex on ':2:' instead.

e.g. `CHARINDEX(':2:', ltrim(rtrim(replace(':' + AA + ':',' ',''))) )`